# Ensure that patch (area) is displayed

Tags: matlab

I want to ensure that the patchs I plot are always displayed, not depending if they are to small compared to the current axes units.

The following minimal code illustrates the issue:

```
axisLim=10000;
figure
hold on 
plot(1:axisLim);
p1=patch([10 10 500 500],[0 axisLim axisLim 0],[1 1 1 1],'EdgeColor','none',wFaceColor','r')
p2=patch([9000 9000 9001 9001],[0 axisLim axisLim 0],[1 1 1 1],'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','none')
```

[image: Small patch doesn't appear]

The patch p1 will be visible, whereas the second won't. Anyone knows how I can make sure that all patchs are visible?

Comment: You need to update your code. There are few errors. If you zoom-in to where x=9000, you would see a red line. The problem is since your x-scale is very large and your second patch has very low width of ratio 1:10000 it is difficult to see/plot

Comment: My mac changes the . . . to … if I type them united. Sorry x(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to this. This should work. For the second patch instead of face color, you are giving it to the edge. Which will make it appear on the plot.

```
axisLim=10000;
figure
hold on 
plot(1:axisLim);
p1=patch([10 10 500 500],[0 axisLim axisLim 0],[1 1 1 1],...
  'EdgeColor','r','FaceColor','r')
p2=patch([9000 9000 9001 9001],[0 axisLim axisLim 0],[1 1 1 1],...
  'FaceColor','r','EdgeColor','r')
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit your answer to put both EdgeColor and FaceColor as red? That way it doesn't matter if the  patch is small or big, it will always be filled and appear.